# SQL server throwing error when inserting with ISNULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull, nvarchar

I have this query

```
INSERT INTO dbo.finaltable (qty)
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(table1.[qty], '0'), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), 
'') as qty FROM dbo.sometable as table1
```

qty column of dbo.finaltable is type decimal(18,4)

When I run it, it will throw the error

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.
```

But when I simply run

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(table1.[qty], '0'), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), 
'') as qty FROM dbo.sometable as table1
```

It is working perfectly. There are NULL values in table1.qty and NULL values are replaced with '0'. ISNULL doesn't seem to work if I used it along with INSERT. What is the problem here?

EDIT: 
I apologize for assuming the error is related to ISNULL. I now understand that it has something to do with the locale. This question should be closed.

Comment: what is the data type of your qty column

Comment: The error talks about *overflows* and *conversions*, not `ISNULL`. It says that you tried to insert something that looks like a number that wouldn't fit in a `decimal(18,4)`. Perhaps you are trying to parse text using the *wrong* locale and eg `123,45` gets parsed as 12345 when it should be 123.45? Post the schema for *both* tables and sample data. BTW if `qty` is a string type, you have a serious design issue. If not, the calls to `REPLACE()` *cause* the problem

Comment: Instead of relying on implicit parsing use `PARSE` or `TRY_PARSE` with the locale that matches the data. If you want to parse eg French or German numeric strings, use `FORMAT(table1.qty,'de-DE')` or `FORMAT(table1.qty,'de-DE')`.

Comment: Datatype of table1.qty is nvarchar(255) but it only contains numbers and I had reasons that I made it nvarchar.

Comment: @Zik - no, it also contains something the looks like a number but *doesn't fit* in a `decimal(18,4)`. Look *there*, not at `ISNULL`.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos The data is either a number or a NULL. I am sure there is no data that has something like 123,45

Comment: @Zik that's your actual problem. The data isn't a number. It contains strings that look like numbers for *some* locales. The decimal and thousand separators are different in the US and Europe for example. If the server's locale or column's collation doesn't match the data, you'll get incorrect results

Comment: @Zik the very fact that `qty` is a text type is a very big bug. You have to know what locale to use in order to parse it. Did someone use a bad BULK INSERT or `bcp` command perhaps, to import the data? Is that why newlines ended up in the field? Maybe you should fix *that* insert of trying to parse the data after the fact?

Comment: A "number" bigger than 99999999999999 will trigger this error, e.g. `SELECT CAST('100000000000000' AS decimal(18,4)) -- arithmetic overflow`. The value is converted by SQL server for insert.

Comment: Alright, thanks everyone.

Comment: @Zik.. How did you find that, your wrongly assuming...?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to examine the contents of table1.qty to see why it can't convert into a numeric data format. I suspect you need to remove some other characters which are non numeric. I would do something like this first to identify what else is going on ; the try_cast will return a null value when it is unable to convert the field to a numeric format, and that allows you to examine any problematic records.

You can then take this logic and use it as a way to filter out all qty values which are incompatible, enabling you to get the inserts done quickly that are easy to do, and letting you fix the ones that aren't in peace.

```
  SELECT 
  REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(table1.[qty], '0'), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') as replaced_values 
  , table1.qty  
  FROM table1
  WHERE
  try_cast(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(table1.[qty], '0'), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10)), '') as numeric(18,4))
  is null
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your data type is not numeric for qty column so its better to change it numeric then just use below query

```
INSERT INTO dbo.finaltable (qty)
SELECT coalesce(table1.[qty], 0) from FROM dbo.sometable as table1
```

Comment: The error is about conversion and overflow, not NULLS

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
INSERT INTO dbo.finaltable (qty)
SELECT  ISNULL(table1.[qty], 0) as qty FROM dbo.sometable as table1
```

Answer (score -1):

> It is working perfectly. There are NULL values in table1.qty and NULL values are replaced with '0'. ISNULL doesn't seem to work if I used it along with INSERT. What is the problem here?

From your statement, I would like to say something that, On `select` statement `convert()` the result of `replace(replace(isnull(..)..)..)`. If it throws error, then you will assuming that error comes during `INSERT`

```
SELECT 
convert(
 decimal(18, 4)
 , REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(table1.[qty], '0'), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), 
   '') 
) as qty 
FROM dbo.sometable as table1
```

I think, I told what I thought and you would understand that.